# What advantages does Lazy<T> offer over standard lazy instantiation?

Tags: c#, lazy-initialization

Consider this example, it shows two possible ways of lazy initialization. 
Except for being thread-safe, are there any specific advantates of using Lazy<T> here?

```
class Customer {
    private decimal? _balance2;
    private static decimal GetBalanceOverNetwork() {
        //lengthy network operations
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return 99.9M;
    }

    public decimal? GetBalance2Lazily() {
        return _balance2 ?? (_balance2 = GetBalanceOverNetwork());
    }

    private readonly Lazy<decimal> _balance1 = new Lazy<decimal>(GetBalanceOverNetwork);

    public Lazy<decimal> Balance1 {
        get { return _balance1; }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Please consider above code as a simple example, data types are irrelevant, the point here is to compare Lazy <T> over standard lazy initialization.

Comment: Given that `_balance1` is already `readonly`, and the accessor doesn't do anything besides return the value, what are you gaining from using a property?

Comment: @Karl, initialization without `private set` and constructor, no?

Comment: @Karl, probably nothing, except another way to confuse my fellow developers.

Comment: Shouldn't GetBalance2Lazily() and Balance1 return a decimal, not decimal? or Lazy<decimal>?

Comment: I used nullable decimal to use this nify null coalescing operator (??). I could easily use decimal type, but that would require more keystrokes.

Comment: Interesting that `Lazy<T>` does not have an implicit (or explicit) conversion to `T`.

Comment: Why do you expose the `Lazy<T>` in your public property? I would have return its value. And why is your first public property `Decimal?`? That the private fields are of these types is understandable. But leaking details about your lazy initialization into the public API is probably not a wise choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is semantically more correct.

When you use the `Nullable<decimal>`, what you say is that the value of `null` will stand for the "unevaluated" state. Although this is a common conversion, it is still arbitrary. There are million other ways to interpret `null`, so you should probably explain somewhere (in the documentation or at least as a comment) what null means in this case.

On the contrary, when you use `Lazy<decimal>`, your intentions are clear.

Comment: Fascinating! I should have thought of this. I often use the colourful term "brain damage" to refer to the inability to see what's more or less semantically correct and/or intuitive, as a result of having been forced by more primitive languages to do things in a more round-about way. It's always a shock to discover that one's own brain has been damaged :)

Comment: I have to take issue with this answer, as it is based on an incorrect assumption in the example code.  `GetBalance2Lazily()` does ***not*** have to return a nullable because it will never return null.  It should instead be written as `public decimal GetBalance2Lazily() => _balance2 ?? (_balance2 = GetBalanceOverNetwork());` (which could also be written as a property, not a function) and since it's not nullable, there's no semantic to explain to a consumer.  As such, this answer technically doesn't address the intent of the original question, at least as titled, and that's what I'm after.